# How to use SQLitePCL execute content of sql file

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to use SQLitePCL package to develop a simple UWP app that executes database commands (create-select-update-delete). I created a database sql file that contains some sqlite commands and I'm trying to execute them in my code:

```
        Uri appUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/db.sql");
        StorageFile sFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(appUri).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string sSQL = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sFile).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        ISQLiteStatement cnStatement = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL);
        cnStatement.Step();
```

But when I run the program, it only executes the first statement in the sql file which is CREATE command and exit without executing the rest of the commands. Here is the sample content of the sql file:

```
  CREATE TABLE Superhero (
  Type    TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  Picture TEXT
  );

  INSERT INTO Superhero (
                     Type,
                     Picture
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     'batman',
                     'batman.ico'
                 );
```

Anyone knows if there is a way in SQLitePCL to execute a sql file?
Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of [sqlite3_prepare](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) interface:

> These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.

So that it seems like  only the first statement in the commands is actually executed. The remainder is silently ignored. Since every command is ended up with symbol ";", for a quick and simple solution, you may just split the sql commands into single statements and then execute one by one. For example:

```
string sSQL = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sFile).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("sun.db", SQLiteOpen.READWRITE);
//using (ISQLiteStatement cnStatement = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL))
//{
//    var result = cnStatement.Step();
//} 
var statements = sSQL.Split(new[] { ';' });
foreach (string onestate in statements)
{
    using (ISQLiteStatement cnStatement = dbConnection.Prepare(onestate))
    {
        var result = cnStatement.Step();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may need to update the `SQLitePCL` Nuget package.